# Why is the st_size field in struct stat signed?

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix

`st_size` is [defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html) as being an `off_t`.

`off_t` is [defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html) as being a **signed integer type**.

Why is `st_size` defined as a signed type? Can it be negative? What does it mean if it is negative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best reason I can think of is to avoid introducing an unsigned version of `off_t` as an extra type; POSIX already has a ridiculous abundance of integer types with similar uses.

Aside from that, being able to store -1 in `st_size` when size is not a concept that makes sense is probably useful; I'm not sure if any implementations do this, and I can't find where POSIX puts any requirements on the contents of `st_size` except for regular files and symlinks...

Comment: Where does POSIX put a requirement for `st_size` for regular files?

Comment: POSIX requires `st_size` to reflect the file's actual size for regular files, and requires it to reflect the symbolic link length for symlinks. The requirement for symlinks is documented with `stat`; the requirement for regular files seems to be omitted there, but the documentation for `sys/stat.h` says that for regular files, `st_size` is the size of the file in bytes.

Answer (score 6):

Under C's promotion rules, expressions combining different sizes of signed types will behave the same arithmetically-correct fashion regardless of the sizes involved provided that none of the intermediate computations overflow.  Adding unsigned types, however, will make code's behavior much more dependent on integer sizes.

Given:

```
int test_size(off_t x, long y, long long z)
{
  return x-y > z;
}
```

If `off_t` were unsigned, then depending upon its size it could cause `y` to get
promoted to `unsigned long`, with computation performed on that type, which would then get promoted to `signed long long` and compared with `z` using a signed comparison, or it could cause `z` to get promoted to `unsigned long long`, in which case the overall comparison would be done in unsigned fashion.  It would also be possible (though not necessarily likely) that `off_t` could be small enough (and/or `long` big enough) that `y` gets subtracted using signed arithmetic.

Quantities that might large enough to require something at least as big as `int`, even if they will never be negative, should generally be represented by unsigned types only if there is reason to believe they won't fit in a particular signed type but would certainly fit in its unsigned counterpart.  Such situations aren't terribly common, but existed with size_t on 16-bit systems (it was architecturally impossible for a single object to exceed 64K, but objects over 32K were commonplace).  Such a scenario would seem less compelling in a file-system interface (if 32-bit signed isn't enough, 32-bit unsigned probably won't be enough for very long either).

Comment: Interesting discourse on mixed type math.  Using `x-y*1LL > z` in this hypothetical may help  a bit, yet still have corner failings. Hmmm.

Answer (score 3):

`off_t` defines offsets in a file, which could be equal to the file's size, but also can be negative, for example if seeking backwards.

From this relation between offset and size, a file's size has the same type as a file offset. Anyhow, a file size shall not be negative.

Answer (score 2):

I think some fseek function in POSIX need to accept negative as offset.

Answer (score 0):

`off_t` is used to handle file offsets in many functions. Some functions use the special value -1 (e.g. `lseek` does that to tell you an error has occurred). Many other data types are signed in UNIX for accommodating -1 values (e.g. `time_t`).

Comment: Note that `lseek`'s argument is a *relative* file position (offset), which is the main reason `off_t` needs to be signed. And the fact that you can only seek to positive absolute file positions imposes a restriction that files cannot be larger than the maximum value of the (signed) type `off_t`, so there's no use in having a `filesize_t` that's unsigned to hold larger values.